# `clang::PluginASTAction` with `clang::tooling::runToolOnCode` produce string output (for tests)?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, libclang, libtooling

With [`clang::tooling::runToolOnCode`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/namespaceclang_1_1tooling.html#ae416ffe2c36c8c9f57181044b4c72252) I can provide [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) input but I only get a [`bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/bool) output.

```c++
static const char
  *const from = "#include <string.h>\n"
                "int main(void) {\n"
                "    for(int i=0; i<strlen(\"FOO\"); i++) {}\n"
                "}\n",
  *const want = "#include <string.h>\n"
                "int main(void) {\n"
                "    for(size_t i=0; i<strlen(\"FOO\"); i++) {}\n"
                "}\n";

clang::tooling::runToolOnCode(std::make_unique<TypeCorrectPluginAction>(), from));
```

How do I get the modified source-code, without outputting to disk and reading from disk?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to achieve this, but if this helps a little, you can check the unittests in clang-tools, specifically: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang-tools-extra/unittests/clang-change-namespace/ChangeNamespaceTests.cpp#L34 .

Comment: @JuanManuel If you can write that up into an answer I can give you the bounty

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how to achieve this specifically, but I have a pointer.

You can check how it's done in the unittests in clang-tools, more specifically: [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang-tools-extra)